# Dockerfile is copying files from outside of parent directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Dockerfile that is in a directory called /App when I build my docker container using a docker-compose yaml file the dockerfile copies files from one level up, outside the /App folder into the container.
Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

and here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  dash:
    build:
      context: ./App
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dash
    container_name: dash_dash
    command: ls
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
```

When I build and run the container the ls command shows that it copied the directory one level above the /App directory, such that the /App directory is included but is not the main directory.

Comment: What is your directory structure in the host ? Please, add it to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `volumes` section of your `docker-compose.yml` is overriding the working directory:

```yaml
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

is copying the whole folder where the `docker-compose.yml` is (so it is copying the `/App` folder entirely). As a result, your files in your working directory (`/code`) are overridden.

You should remove the `volumes` section of your `docker-compose.yml`. The `ls` command will then show the contents of the `App` directory, copied by the `COPY . .` section of your `Dockerfile`.